# Facing some issues while building ionic-4 project

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic4, ecmascript-5

I am facing some issues while building an ionic-4 project for android, the command line stops at `Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading`.

Here is the screenshot and error report:

[image: Error Report]

```
[error] Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (F:\Petrol Price App\27 New chart\app\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:193:21)
    at ChildProcessWorker.onExit (F:\Petrol Price App\27 New chart\app\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:263:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Run the same command with "--verbose", add that error log in the question. It would tell more about the error source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had similar issue and was able to fix my build by for the moment changing the tsconfig.app.json target from `es2015` back down to `es5`, this disabled differential loading.

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading